# get value from onInput event for cotentEditable in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, contenteditable

I have a contentEditable header in which I want to get the value on `onInput` event. So far, I have managed to get `event.target` but it returns the entire DOM node. I want to get only the actual value of the header. Helpful ideas are highly appreciated.

What I have tried so far:

1. `console.log(e.target.value)` --> returns `undefined`
2. `console.log(e.target)` --> returns the node `<h5 contenteditable="true" style="margin: 0px;">Lesson 1</h5>`
3. I also thought to convert node to string and extract the value using reg ex, but I had to give up when `console.log(e.target.toString())` return `[object HTMLHeadingElement]`

```js
<h5 contentEditable style={{ margin: 0 }} onInput={e => {
          props.onChangeName(e.target.value)
          console.log(e.target)
      }}>
        {props.name}
</h5>
```

Comment: `console.log(e.target.textContent)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.value` only works for forms html component. Using `contentEditable` allows you to edit the [innerHtml](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) of your markup. To access the actual content, you can run:

```js
<h5 contentEditable style={{ margin: 0 }} onInput={e => {
      props.onChangeName(e.target.innerHTML);
      //or
      props.onChangeName(e.target.textContent);
  }}>
  {props.name}
</h5>
```